# Get value from URL (address bar with manually type) use input hidden html

Tags: java, html

I'm trying to get value from URL (address bar) in example :
I want to get order_id from `kamumau/feedbacks?action=new&order_id=1`

this my html code

```
<div>
   <input type="hidden" id="order_id" name="order_id"/>
</div>
```

and this my java code

```
int order_id = Integer.parseInt(request.getParameter("order_id"));
```

But i still get empty value. Anyone?

Comment: share a whole controller method please

Comment: https://pastebin.com/ZYmwYx5J @YuriyTsarkov

Comment: what does request return on `getQueryString()`? It should be `action=new&order_id=1`. If don't then problem is somewhere upper in a code